# How can I stop hbrBackground, painting, on resize? C++

Tags: c++, windows

I have removed CS_HREDRAW, CS_VREDRAW.

Messages WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND do nothing, yet as soon as the window is re-sized it repaints it with the background colour. Is there any way to stop it drawing / repainting at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can set default background brush to `NULL`

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
...
wcex.hbrBackground = NULL;
RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
```

Or return `TRUE` for `WM_ERASEBKGND` (in addition to doing nothing)

```
switch(msg)
{
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    return TRUE;
...
}
```

Use either method to prevent background paint message.

For `WM_PAINT` either don't handle the message or use with `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` calls. If there is no background brush then you probably need to handle `WM_PAINT`

You may also want to add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag to your window, to prevent painting behind child controls.

Comment: As stated in the question, WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND, both messages return 0. I have not tried WS_CLIPCHILDREN but as it re-paints the background anyway I don't think it will have any effect.

Comment: It is not stated in the question that they return zero, and I did not suggest that they should return zero. `WM_ERASEBKGND` should return `TRUE` if you don't want background painting. What is it you are trying to do?